# Github Jekyll site builds locally but ignores header tags online

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

this is a very curious Jekyll github issue that i can't figure out.

I have a repo here where i'm developing tutorials

https://github.com/NEONInc/NEON-DataSkills-Lesson-Development

If you go to it online, you'll notice that while there markdown posts in the _posts directory have headers as follows

```
#Header One
##Header Two
```

They do not render online. Instead notice that even the landing page:

http://neoninc.github.io/NEON-DataSkills-Lesson-Development/

Renders the top heading as

```
##Welcome to the NEON #WorkWithData Portal!
```

instead of

### Welcome to the NEON #WorkWithData Portal!

Here is the most curious part - it renders FINE locally when i do "jekyll" build. I have tried

1. Replacing all style sheets and template layout files
2. rechecking the config file.
3. recloning the repo from a different account on a different computer to see if the build rendered the heading tags using ## rather than using heading styles. It still rendered fine locally.

One other quirk - if you go to a lesson - for instance

http://neoninc.github.io/NEON-DataSkills-Lesson-Development/R/EML

notice that the line spacing in the code blocks is wide -The line spacing locally is LESS and looks much better. So someone the css is being partially ignored?

I am not sure what else to try to get things to render properly- or to render consistently between github online and a local build. Especially given I can not replicate the issue locally. Any guidance as to what else I can try to fix this render issue?

NOTE: This same repo skin is used in other repos and renders online JUST FINE. so this issue is specific to this particular repo.

Example: http://neoninc.github.io/NEONDS-Template-Repository/

Many thanks for ANY ideas.
Leah

Comment: NOTE: i just tried to update JEKYLL locally to v 3.x. I still can't replicate this issue that i see online. I also fixed some deprecated code in my config file.

Comment: Where is actual post located? I did not found in _post directory, too many R and Rmd file, which I have never used. Have you tried space after ## sign?  If I was there, then I will include _toc.html file in layout folder not in specific post. also I will categories post in specific page, not in layout folder. You can do such a thing very simply, but you complicated it :) Well, you can even use HTML tags directly in markdown file like <h2 > header </ h2>.

Comment: Hello @goyllo I probably did write overly complicated code :) here is an easier repo w fewer files. The rendered page: http://chayadecacao.github.io/deleteMe/R/Boulder-Flood-Overview5/. ..the post in git  https://github.com/chayadecacao/deleteMe/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2015-12-03-Boulder-Flood-Lesson.md hopefully this helps clarify? I'm trying go deconstruct the issue by removing elements from the site. Thank u for the feedback! !

Comment: So this repo, run fine in your local server? Because I have downloaded, and build it, and it's working fine in my local host, look's like you are using too many things in config file, So I just deleted all the thing, and using only kramdown markdown. - https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0

Comment: Try adding a space after `#`. So instead of `#Title` you'll have `# Title `.

Comment: thank you all! it was the space causing the issues.  i'm so appreciative of the input on this issue. I posted an answer below following an email for GitHub because this wasn't impacting ALL of my sites, just some. And it did used to render just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback. I wanted to post a solution to this issue after talking with GitHub. Github is migrating to Jekyll 3.0 as pointed out in the comments! (thank you!)

https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0

This migration is impacting markdown - moving to a more strict version of Kramdown which does not render headers as

```
#Header One Will render as a paragraph rather than a header
```

instead if requires a space after the #

```
# Header One Renders as a header (h1) tag
```

In short, Kramdown used to accept #header syntax but no longer. I am noticing my repos where I have been using #Header syntax render incorrectly one by one. I don't have clarification on why it's impacting some and not all. I also am unclear as to why things render fine locally. The solution in short is - add a space after your # AND if your repos look fine now, be prepared for them to not render properly in the future.

I hope this helps others dealing with migration issues!  I am also having to adjust some of my code block styles for various reasons.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! :)